# Meteor babel config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, babeljs

In babel config file "babel.json", I want to exclude/ignore specific files

I found this solution but this ignore all other js files.

```
{
  "extensions": ["es6.js"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{
   "extensions": ["es6.js", "es6"]
}
```

Otherwise you might want to try find another package to handle what you're working with because the `grigio/meteor-babel` package is depreciated.

If you want to ignore a specific JS File you could just comment out the the whole file as a quick fix.

Comment: but this will treat only files with extension es6.js and es6 and ignore all other js files. what I want is only ignore one or two files

Comment: What specific files would you like to ignore?

Comment: client/template/gestion/go.js

Comment: Ah, well as mentioned the package you're using is depreciated so you may want to either try something else or just comment out all the code in go.js

Comment: I can't comment the code because I need it, the problem is just on each server start I should wait that babel optimise the file then after 3 - 5 min it tells me that babel couldn't optimize the file and has ignore it. It's not a big deal but I just want to forget this and focus on the app.